# Destroying and Recreating a Panel wx.Python

Tags: wxpython

This is the bane of my life:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:\Users\User\Documents\PYTHON\GAME FILES\simple.py", line 18, in OnDestroy
>      self.Destroy()
>    File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-ansi\wx_core.py", line 14610, in *getattr*_
>      raise PyDeadObjectError(self.attrStr % self._name)
>   wx._core.PyDeadObjectError: The C++ part of the MyPanels object has been deleted, attribute > access no longer allowed.

My Goal:  To have two panels, with the left panel killing and "recreating" the right panel/an identical copy via buttons, simulating how a user can make a choice in the left hand panel about what they want to see and have the right panel display this.  That's what I'm trying to do in my more complicated programme, but that was failing, so am trying to learn how to destroy and recreate a blank panel here.  Still same TERRIFYING error.

Code:

```
import wx
import sys
import traceback


def show_error():
    message = ''.join(traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info()))
    dialog = wx.MessageDialog(None, message, 'Error!', wx.OK|wx.ICON_ERROR)
    dialog.ShowModal()

class MyPanels(wx.Panel):

 def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

 def OnDestroy(self, event):

    self.Destroy()

 def OnTest(self, event):
    print "Hello"

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(1000, 480))
        self.parent = parent

        self.panel = MyPanels(self, -1)
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour("grey")

        self.panel.leftpanel = MyPanels(self.panel, 1)
        self.panel.rightpanel = MyPanels(self.panel, 1)
        self.panel.leftpanel.SetBackgroundColour("red")
        self.panel.rightpanel.SetBackgroundColour("green")

        self.panel.basicsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.panel.basicsizer.Add(self.panel.leftpanel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.panel.basicsizer.Add(self.panel.rightpanel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.panel.SetSizer(self.panel.basicsizer)

        button =  wx.Button(self.panel.leftpanel, 1, 'DIE DIE DIE', (50, 130))
        buttonres = wx.Button(self.panel.leftpanel, 2, 'Resurrect', (50, 230))
        buttonextra = wx.Button(self.panel.leftpanel, 3, 'Test', (50, 330))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.panel.rightpanel.OnDestroy, id = 1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.CreateNewPanel, id = 2)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.panel.rightpanel.OnTest, id = 3)




    def CreateNewPanel(self, event):
        self.panel.rightpanel = MyPanels(self.panel, 1)
        self.panel.rightpanel.SetBackgroundColour("green")

        self.panel.basicsizer.Add(self.panel.rightpanel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.panel.SetSizer(self.panel.basicsizer)

        self.panel.rightpanel.Refresh()
        self.panel.leftpanel.Refresh()
        self.panel.leftpanel.Layout()
        self.panel.leftpanel.Update()
        self.panel.Layout()
        self.Update()


        self.Show(True)
        self.Centre()



def main():
    app = wx.App()
    try:
        frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'Die.py')
        frame.Show()
        app.MainLoop()
    except:
        show_error()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Essentially, it seems like I've (finally) got the Resurrect Button to work, at least in that the 'new' panel fills the appropriate space.  But if I try to Kill it again, that's when the scary error pops up.

I've been researching the error message, and it seems I'm getting this because the self.Destroy() destroyed something that is still needed by something in the programme.  I'm finding this difficult to understand, because I thought I was creating a perfect identical copy, down to the same name.

The only thing I think it can be is the Kill button itself.  It's as if it requires the original rightpanel to destroy again, that it is locked into its unique class reference, rather than its name of rightpanel.  I added a third button to test it.  This third button has almost identical code, it just calls a different Method in the MyPanels class.  And...it still works after the Kill and Resurrect.  But pressing Kill again does not work.  The only difference between them is that the OnDestroy method uses 'self'.

Somehow I guess I have got to stop the Kill button's event binding itself to the 'self' of the original right panel.  I am utterly lost.  I've tried hopelessly telling the left panel to refresh/update itself.  Nothing.  Have spent the last two days trying to work this out.  I'm new to python and wxpython and am utterly in over my head here, but please, please help me out.

EDITED-

ok, had a mini-brainwave just now.  I think once an event is bound with the Bind command, it is bound to that widget forever, unless it is changed.  That is why it is still clinging to a dead panel.  **So if I unbind it and then rebind it, is that the solution?**

I've changed the button name to self.button.  And then in the def CreateNewPanel() method, I've put an Unbind command in...and then immediately put copy pasted the Bind command.  It seems to be working now!!!!

But...  can someone tell me:
 1) is this the right solution or just some cumbersome workaround that I've come up with
and 2) Why why why does the whole frame jump half an inch across my screen when I call 
            self.panel.rightpanel.Refresh()?

**
Edit -

Now that I seem to be able to destroy and recreate RightPanel based on LeftPanel's buttons, I've tried to manage this on the complex programme.  *The complex programme is designed to show information (bio + pic) of a character in the RightPanel, based on user selection of a listctrl of names on LeftPanel*.

So it's very similar to this:  instead of having an empty RightPanel, it has tons of widgets.

And it does work...to an extent.  If I click to see Character X, RightPanel destroys itself and then recreates itself with Character Y's widgets.  Yay.  But it also temporarily *flashes a tiny little square* to the top left corner of RightPanel that clearly contains copies of all the widgets.

This square vanishes almost immediately, but it's clearly visible everytime you click to change RightPanel's contents.  It's pretty ugly.  I just can't get rid of it!  I've tried dotting in .Layout() everywhere and to everything, nope.  Can't work out why it would appear and then disappear!  Is it a programme delay that I can't get rid of?  Or some error I'm making with my sizers?  Must stress - the widgets lay out perfectly as I intended...so the sizers are surely working fine...right?  **

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you are tying everything together in a very odd manner. You don't normally create nested panels by doing MyPanel.panel = wx.Panel(). Instead, you create them the normal way you create any panel:

```
panelOne = wx.Panel(self)
panelTwo = wx.Panel(self)
panelThree = MyPanels(parent, id)
```

I would also avoid creating sizers the way you do. I use something like

```
mySizer = wx.BoxSizer()
```

I ended up cleaning out a bunch of the weird junk to make this work. I don't see a reason to destroy the panel, so I just hid it instead:

```
import wx
import sys
import traceback

def show_error():
    message = ''.join(traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info()))
    dialog = wx.MessageDialog(None, message, 'Error!', wx.OK|wx.ICON_ERROR)
    dialog.ShowModal()

class MyPanels(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(1000, 480))
        self.parent = parent

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour("grey")

        self.leftpanel = MyPanels(self.panel, 1)
        self.rightpanel = MyPanels(self.panel, 1)
        self.leftpanel.SetBackgroundColour("red")
        self.rightpanel.SetBackgroundColour("green")

        self.basicsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.basicsizer.Add(self.leftpanel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.basicsizer.Add(self.rightpanel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.panel.SetSizer(self.basicsizer)

        button =  wx.Button(self.leftpanel, 1, 'DIE DIE DIE', (50, 130))
        buttonres = wx.Button(self.leftpanel, 2, 'Resurrect', (50, 230))
        buttonextra = wx.Button(self.leftpanel, 3, 'Test', (50, 330))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.destroyPanel, button)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.CreateNewPanel, buttonres)

    def CreateNewPanel(self, event):
        self.rightpanel = MyPanels(self.panel, 1)
        self.rightpanel.SetBackgroundColour("green")
        self.basicsizer.Add(self.rightpanel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.panel.Layout()

        self.Show(True)
        self.Centre()

    def destroyPanel(self, event):
        self.rightpanel.Hide()
        self.panel.Layout()

def main():
    app = wx.App()
    try:
        frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'Die.py')
        frame.Show()
        app.MainLoop()
    except:
        show_error()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This exercise reminded me of my panel switching article from a couple years ago: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/16/wxpython-how-to-switch-between-panels/

Maybe that will help you too.

Comment: Hi, I'm a little confused about the nested panel thing.  Probably because I struggle with object references.  At some point, probably when I first began prefacing objects with self.  , I assumed that they could only be accessed via their parent.  Have rewritten code, and it does work with the simplified refs.

Comment: 2nd point - re the destroy vs hide.  I chose to destroy because this script is just to isolate how to destroy and recreate.  In my proper programme, there is a toolbar at the top and a listctrl at the left, and these are meant to change the display in RightPanel.  Users can switch between areas via the toolbar, and also characters.  So I thought destroy would be simpler than hide, otherwise the programme would be juggling loads and loads of hidden panels, which would take up memory.

Comment: But I'd be interested to know what are the adv/disadv of panel.destroy compared to panel.hide.   I'm wondering if the little flashing square I'm experiencing is a consequence of using destroy and recreate...that perhaps it is slowing the programme down?  Have edited the main post about this curious little square that disappears almost instantly but can't be missed, thus making the programme look bad.  I'd be interested to know if I should indeed be looking into reorganizing the programme to make hiding the panels feasible.

Comment: Actually, really should thank you for introducing me to hide and show.  I still have no idea what flaw in my code is creating the flashing square, but I can now mask it.  Am calling hide instantly as the RightPanel is created.  Then I call the function which pops the new widgets on RightPanel.  This is when the flashing square would appear.  But as the panel is hidden, it can't show.  Take that, square.  Then I tell it to show.  So the transitions between the different RightPanel characters is all smooth and importantly squareless now.  But still don't understand what causes the square.

Comment: Probably the easiest way to hide the flashing artifact is to use the Freeze and Thaw methods. I went with Hide() in this example because of the way you had tied everything together. Using Destroy() seemed to destroy elements unintentionally when everything was tied together like that. Separating things out should allow you to use Destroy again though.

Comment: Thanks. :) Freeze and Thaw are working really well in my antisquare quest.  I just wish there was a tutorial that explained/mentioned them before!

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, that's the right solution, although more pythonic way would be to Unbind the `Die` button at the same time you destroy the panel so that pressing that button multiple times would not throw an exception. Something like this should do:

   ```
   self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnPanelDestroy, id = 1)

   def OnPanelDestroy(self, event):
       self.Unbind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, id = 1)
       self.panel.rightpanel.OnDestroy(event)

   def CreateNewPanel(self, event):
       self.panel.rightpanel = MyPanels(self.panel, 1)
       self.panel.rightpanel.SetBackgroundColour("green")
       self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnPanelDestroy, id = 1)
   ```
2. If I understood you correctly, that's because of calling `self.Centre()` rather than `self.panel.rightpanel.Refresh()`. If you comment it out, the frame wouldn't center on the screen, but stay put.

Comment: Hi, 
Thank you very much!  You were right about the self.Centre(), I've adjusted it and it's stopped skipping around the screen.  I've popped this all back into the original proper programme (essentially like this only with a listctrl of people's names instead of buttons on LeftPanel, which produces a ton of widgets including character bio and picture on RightPanel according to whoever is selected), and it does work now... although weirdly I keep getting a tiny little square in the topleft corner of RightPanel....the layout is perfect, except for this square appearing for about 1s. *confused*